# Modal with title, subject, and time posted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This might be easy for some, but I'm struggling to make this work.
I created a modal that has title, subject (input area) and timestamp when you click submit.
I would like to output title, subject, and time posted as a list item `<li></li>`.

```
var main = function(){
$('.btn-primary').click(function(){

    var title = $('#message-title').val();
    var post = $('#message-text').val(); 
     $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.livefeed');

      var currentTime = new Date();
      var n = currentTime.toLocaleDateString();
      document.getElementById("timestamp").innerHTML = n

      $('#message-text').val();

  });

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

[Here is the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiuR1.jpg)

Comment: can you please create a fiddle  ?

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon or is this a typo `document.getElementById("timestamp").innerHTML = n`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo " ; ". Dont know how to create a fiddle. What i am trying to achieve is when fields are entered such as "Title", "Subject" and click submit using modal. The message output which will be similar to a twitter or facebook status, must contain " title" + "Subject " and time stamp all in one line or 1 list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function(){

var title = $('#message-title').val();
var post = $('#message-text').val();
var currentTime = new Date();
var n = currentTime.toLocaleDateString();
$('ul').append('<li>'+title+' '+post+' '+n+'</li>');

});
```

Comment: Shubham thank you for the reply. the above code works but it prints out 3 list items. But I would like my (title + post + time) all to appear as on list item instead of three. Sorry if i didnt post it right.

Comment: @NewCoder I have updated my code according to your need please go through that and check it again.

Comment: some progress but this is how it prints.
"SuperBowlSunday+ This Sunday is championship game between NFC and AFC+1/30/2017 "
Trying to remove the "plus" signs after Sunday and AFC, the code doesnt work

Comment: @NewCoder I have updated my code replaced plus sign with space hope this is the thing that you want.

Comment: @NewCoder Please explain me better how you want to display it.

Comment: @NewCoder my pleasure.